# Run Angular Universal dev:ssr and Choose The Environment

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Is it possible to run `npm run dev:ssr` and give it an environment flag?

E.G.: `npm run dev:ssr -c local`?

I would like to run an environment named "local" when I am running on my localhost.

The reason for this is because I have to keep swapping the value for the `distFolder` variable in my `server.ts` file, depending on whether I am running on `localhost` with `npm run dev:ssr`, or running on an emulated STAGING environment with `firebase emulators:start`.

Would love to automate this by writing `environment.name == 'local' ? 'browser' : 'dist/functions/browser'`.

**WHAT I TRIED**

I created a new environment file called `environment.local.ts`, and updated `firebaserc` files, and then added info about the local environment to `angular.json`.

I then ran `ng serve --configuration=local`, and confirmed that this worked as expected.

I then ran `npm run dev:ssr --configuration=local`, but this had no effect.

Neither did `npm run dev:ssr -c local`.

I can tell it isn't working, because I have some console.log messages telling me which environment I'm in, and it never says "Environment Name = local" when I run the :ssr command.

Here's a snippet from my **angular.json** file:

`````
"serve": {
       "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
       "options": {},
       "configurations": {
         "production": {
           "browserTarget": "my-project:build:production"
         },
         "development": {
           "browserTarget": "my-project:build:development"
         },
         "local": {
           "browserTarget": "my-project:build:local"
         }
       },
       "defaultConfiguration": "development"
     },
     "server": {
       "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
       "options": {
         "outputPath": "dist/functions/server",
         "main": "server.ts",
         "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
         "optimization": false,
         "sourceMap": true,
         "extractLicenses": false
       },
       "configurations": {
         "test": {
           "fileReplacements": [
             {
               "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
               "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
             }
           ]
         },
         "production": {
           "outputHashing": "media",
           "fileReplacements": [
             {
               "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
               "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
             }
           ],
           "optimization": true,
           "sourceMap": false,
           "extractLicenses": true
         },
         "local": {
           "fileReplacements": [
             {
               "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
               "with": "src/environments/environment.local.ts"
             }
           ]
         },
         "development": {}
       },
       "defaultConfiguration": "development"
     },
     "serve-ssr": {
       "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
       "configurations": {
         "local": {
           "browserTarget": "my-project:build:local",
           "serverTarget": "my-project:server:local"
         },
         "development": {
           "browserTarget": "my-project:build:development",
           "serverTarget": "my-project:server:development"
         },
         "production": {
           "browserTarget": "my-project:build:production",
           "serverTarget": "my-project:server:production"
         }
       },
       "defaultConfiguration": "development"
     },
 ````
`````

Comment: `npm run dev:ssr -- --configuration production`?

Comment: You are passing your parameter to `npm` but need to pass it to `dev:ssr` instead by inserting a `--`. Everything after this is passed to the subscript

Comment: I regret to say that this does not work.
I tried running:
`npm run dev:ssr -- --configuration local`
RESULT:

`Error: Unknown argument: configuration.
Provide the configuration as part of the target 'ng run my-project:serve-ssr:local'.`


Oh, er. Let me try what it's telling me try! Will update soon :)

Comment: **UPDATE::** Ah FINALLY. I have it working when I run::

`ng run my-project:serve-ssr:local`

And now I don't have to keep switching where my `distFolder`'s `websiteFileLocation` is whenever I choose to run on` local`, versus `staging`. 

Yay!

Answer (score 3):

I have figured this out, thanks to an error message I received when I ran @PieterJan's suggestion in my terminal.

I ran:
`npm run dev:ssr -- --configuration local`

And received this error message:

`Error: Unknown argument: configuration. Provide the configuration as part of the target 'ng run my-project:serve-ssr:local'`

So, I ran:
`ng run my-project:serve-ssr:local`

And it knew it was on the local environment when it booted up!

**UPDATE**
I have also discovered that I can update my package.json so that I can add the environment to the script commands, like this::

```
"scripts":  {
  "dev:ssr:local": "ng run my-project-name:serve-ssr:local",
  "dev:ssr:dev": "ng run my-project-name:serve-ssr:development",
  "dev:ssr:prod": "ng run my-project-name:serve-ssr:production",

}
```

And now I can just run `npm run dev:ssr:local` in my terminal.
Easier to remember and easier to run :-)